# Bypass the 24 snapshot limitation in set-vmreplication -RecoveryHistory. (powershell,hyperv replica)

Tags: powershell, replication, hyper-v, disaster-recovery

It my first question in here,
I work in project to automate hyper-v replica solution.

so my problem is that in powershell

```
set-vmreplication -RecoveryHistory
```

> -RecoveryHistory

has 24 like a max value and i want to pypass that my need it's 72.

1. i try to see the code source but it's in binary i can't do anything
   in that way (**#microsoft** : * _ *:).
2. i post in microsoft forum and nothing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/En3ZE.png)
the error (in french) it say **72 > 24** that all.

so if someone has a solution or a beginning of solution that will be very helpfull.

thank you all.
and have a nice day.

---

@gvee #gvee

### Hi and thank you for your help but...

i test that in my lab and that's not true the ps cmd :

> Set-VMReplication VM01 -RecoveryHistory 24 -VSSSnapshotFrequencyHour 4

it does 24 snapshot and every 4 hours it does a synch snapshot and in total i have 24 snapshots( 18 standart ans 6 coherent )

so in final it doesn't solve my initial problem : `store more than 24 hours snap with hyper-v replica`

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to achieve? Why would you need more than 24 recovery points? As the 24 is [documented a limit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/set-vmreplication?view=win10-ps) there's no easy way around it. To find out more suitable a solution depends on what's the root need.

Comment: hi, my need it's more than 24h,
It is assumed that a vm is corrected on a Friday evening and that the administrator only sees it on Monday. Then the 24 snapshots will be obsolete.
that's why i want more than 24 snapshot.

Comment: i saw the microsoft doc and i want some solution or  a track.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is well documented that 24 is the maximum value allowed for `-RecoveryHistory`.

**[`-RecoveryHistory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/set-vmreplication?view=win10-ps#optional-parameters)**

> Specifies whether to store additional recovery points on the Replica virtual machine. Storing more than the most recent recovery point of the primary virtual machine allows you to recover to an earlier point in time. However, storing additional recovery points requires more storage and processing resources. **You can configure as many as 24 recovery points to be stored.**

Based on your comment:

> my need it's more than 24h

It sounds like you're assuming your interval can only be `24*1hr`; which is untrue.

The `24` snapshots is a fixed maximum; but you can change the *frequency* the snapshots are taken using the `-VSSSnapshotFrequencyHour` parameter.

> Specifies the frequency, in hours, at which Volume Shadow Copy Service (VSS) performs a snapshot backup of the virtual machines

So for example you could do:

```
Set-VMReplication VM01 -RecoveryHistory 24 -VSSSnapshotFrequencyHour 4
```

Effectively that would give you 4 days of history!

Comment: @kintikan You see, this is why one should ask about the _problem_, not the _solution attempt_. See the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @ vonPryz will do that.

Comment: Hi, i test that in my lab and that's not true at all.

Comment: The VSS snapshot frequency is not a multiplier.  It is an indication of how many (aka "how often") of the snapshots use VSS versus how many don't.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an older post but I would like to accomplish the same thing, 3 days or more of checkpoints.  Why?  Because Ransomware tends to strike over weekends.  My replica would be useless by Monday.  What I have done is enable previous versions on my replica target so that I can restore a previous version of a replica that might be a month old or 4 days old.  At least the data will be there and in the meantime I can figure out how to restore it.  Aside from this I plan to use extended replication to another server and Veeam replication.  Hopefully I will come up with a cleaner solution once I start seeing how these technologies work.   Wondering what others are doing about this?  Replication for 24 hours is not enough.

Comment: I would like the same things, is there some uservoice link that we could vote to get this limit. Personally I would like to set at least 1 week, during big holiday we could get more than 1 week off.